# SQL - Salary difference between 2 months (Variance)

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 2 separate SQL queries that returning NetPay amount MonthWise. I 
want to combine them means i want Variance between 2 months
(Month 2 Amount - Month 1 Amount) as output.

```
Query - 1
Select ISNULL(Sum(EPS.Amount),0) as Amount
From Payslip EPS
Where EPS.Emp_Id = 5 and EPS.Month_Id = 5

Query - 2
Select ISNULL(Sum(EPS.Amount),0) as Amount
From Payslip EPS
Where EPS.Emp_Id = 5 and EPS.Month_Id = 6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @month1 INT
DECLARE @month2 INT

SET @month1= 5
SET @month2= 6

Select (a.month1Amount-b.month2Amount) AS Variance from
(Select ISNULL(Sum(EPS.Amount),0) as month1Amount,EPS.Emp_Id
From Payslip EPS
Where EPS.Emp_Id = 5 and EPS.Month_Id =@month1 GROUP BY EPS.Emp_Id)a
INNER JOIN 
(Select ISNULL(Sum(EPS.Amount),0) as month2Amount, EPS.Emp_Id
From Payslip EPS
Where EPS.Emp_Id = 5 and EPS.Month_Id =@month2  GROUP BY EPS.Emp_Id)b
on a.Emp_Id=b.Emp_Id
```

You can Provide Month dynamically. Hope this works

Comment: Giving Error :
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'Employee_PaySlip.Emp_Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Conditional Aggregation` to combine those two queries

```
Select Sum(case EPS.Month_Id when 6 then EPS.Amount else -EPS.Amount end) as Variance 
From Payslip EPS
Where EPS.Emp_Id = 5 and EPS.Month_Id in (6,5)
```

or

```
Select Sum(case EPS.Month_Id when 6 then EPS.Amount else 0 end) - 
       Sum(case EPS.Month_Id when 5 then EPS.Amount else 0 end)
From Payslip EPS
Where EPS.Emp_Id = 5 and EPS.Month_Id in (6,5)
```

You can replace the months in `where` clause and `Case` statement if it is not fixed.

Another approach for using months dynamic

```
SELECT Isnull(A.Amount, 0) - Isnull(B.amount, 0)
FROM   (SELECT months,
               Amount = Sum(Amount)
        FROM   #payslips
        GROUP  BY months) a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT months,
                         Amount = Sum(Amount)
                  FROM   #payslips
                  GROUP  BY months) b
              ON a.months = b.months + 1
WHERE  a.months = 6
       AND b.months = 5
```

For newer versions we can use `LAG` window function

Comment: you cant fix month id

Comment: @Dilip which version of sql server you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to join in same query for your better visibility, use Union all

```
Select Amount1-Amount As Variance
from 
(
Select ISNULL(Sum(EPS.Amount),0) as Amount, '0.00' Amount1
From Payslip EPS
Where EPS.Emp_Id = 5 and EPS.Month_Id = 5

UNION ALL 

Select '0.00' Amount, ISNULL(Sum(EPS.Amount),0) as Amount1
From Payslip EPS
Where EPS.Emp_Id = 5 and EPS.Month_Id = 6

)am
```